# Mongoose adding select prevent returning to client

Tags: angularjs, node.js, mongoose

Got the following code:

On AngularJS client:

```
var getDocs = function() {
            return $http.get('/api/docs/list')
                .then(function(result) {
                    return result.data; // bookmark1 line
                });
        }
```

On Node.Js BE:

```
function getDocs() {
    return Doc.find({}).exec()
            .then(function success(docs) {
                return res.send(docs);
            });
}
```

Works perfectly.
When I change the first line in getDocs() to

```
return Doc.find({}).select('-field1 -field2').exec()
```

I see the docs after the query execution without the fields (as expected) but for some reason The http is pending and chrome debugger is not stopping on the success callback of the client (bookmark1 line).

**Edit:**
Changed to

```
return Cv.find({}).select('-field1 -field2').exec(function success(err, cvs) {
            return res.send(cvs);
        });
```

Got the following error in client:
[image]

**Solution:**
Well It turn out I had another field which depends on field1

```
docSchema.virtual('field3').get(function () {
    return this.field1.toString("base64");
});
```

It fails and for some reason it didnt appear on my IDE. 
I Added a null check and that solve the problem.

Not sure if I should remove this question or maybe it has value for other people. Feel free to say what you think.

Comment: `;` in `return Doc.find({}).select('-field1 -field2').exec();` is intentional?

Comment: No, my mistake, will edit.

Comment: callback approach is working instead of promise ? e.g. `exec(function (err, doc) {});`

Comment: Thanks @Mukesh Sharma, Good direction, checked that out see my edit.

Comment: return  `JSON.stringify(docs)` instead of `docs`.